# SQL Import - cells contains white space

Tags: mysql, sql

I have imported an excel spreadsheet into sql server table, if i copy and paste a cell into notepad for example it contains a lot of white space after the word

e.g.

```
"absconding

"
```

But it should just be:

```
"absconding"
```

Another example:

```
"access to healthcare

"
```

so does like a line break, i could trim all spaces in that column, but there are a lot of entries which are sentences

is there a way to get rid of all white space after the final word/s?

Comment: You've tagged `mysql` but that seems irrelevant here. Would you want to do this data clean up in Excel?

Comment: check the edits, someone removed that tag

Comment: No problem, hope your problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TRIM()`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-trim-function.php) function. MySQL TRIM() function returns a string after removing all prefixes or suffixes from the given string.

```
TRIM([{BOTH | LEADING | TRAILING} [remstr] FROM ] str)
```

Example:

```
SELECT TRIM(' trim ');
```

Output:

```
trim
```

For your case, data is already in the database and you want to clean up the spaces or any other unwanted characters, you can use the `TRIM` function in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE tblGloss 
SET 
    TITLE = TRIM(Replace(Replace(TITLE,'\t',''),'\n',''));
```

Note - If you want to remove only leading or trailing spaces, you can use other string functions: `LTRIM` and `RTRIM`.

Comment: I have around 580 rows in my table, the column name is called "TITLE" and table name is called "tblGloss"

Comment: do tell me, if there's any problem

Comment: Each time i run it, it says changed the same amount of rows each time and isnt applying for some reason ..

Comment: include "\n" with " " in trim function

Comment: It's not really giving an error, saying it is changing 463 rows, but not removing the space

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 130
Incorrect syntax near '\n '.

it is giving this error with the line break

Comment: get the following error: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 5
'TRIM' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Question is tagged `sql server`, you're answer uses `mysql` specific function.

Comment: it was mysql when i started coding

Comment: you are using `sql server` or `mysql`?

Comment: chameleon question. -1 for the question too for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: and what's my mistake in this, if op changes tags?

Comment: @:Abhishek Keshri i didnt change the tag?!? i really do appreciate the help!

Comment: Okay, no problem... Happy to help :)

Comment: @lanes123 which database are you using? Your error messages indicate that you're running the query on Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `replace` to remove line breaks and `rtrim` to remove spaces at right:

```
declare @x varchar(200)
set @x='absconding

'
select rtrim(replace(replace(@x,CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),''))
```

Comment: This will work for that one word, but not an entire column?

Comment: It works for the column, I've used `@x` to demonstrate only

Comment: what if there is `\r` or `\n` in the middle of string?